# how to view full output on sklearn on the gaggle website

Tags: scikit-learn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ztnm.png)This is the output of my algorithm on kaggle using sklearn. How can I see the folded part (the "..." part) above?

I tried all buttons on the interface but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.to_string()` --> [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)
This will simply print the entire thing to the cell below.

If you know the exact range that you want to view I would suggest to just view  that slice with `df[range_start, range_stop].to_string()`

I think every dataframe longer than 50 entries will be displayed folded.